# null pointer exception error eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

this is a program that call getDetails class. when it calls getDetails it got this error. I tried getDetails code sepretaly and it works. but when I call it from this class it shows me this error. i upload the picture of error here:
[image]

It think it related to this line:

```
  Cursor names = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

the code

```
public class SmsFilter extends BroadcastReceiver {
 SharedPreferences preferences = null ;
    Context context = null;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("modes",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {

         Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])extras.get("pdus");

            if (pdus.length < 1) return; // Invalid SMS. Not sure that it's possible.

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String sender = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                if (sender == null) sender = message.getOriginatingAddress();
                String text = message.getMessageBody();
                if (text != null) sb.append(text);
            }
            if (preferences.getBoolean("enable", true)==false) {



            if (preferences.getBoolean("all", true)){ abortBroadcast();}



            else if (preferences.getBoolean("blacklist", true)){

            boolean str=Search.search(sender);

                if (sender != null && str ==true) {


                 abortBroadcast();

            }

            }
            else    if (preferences.getBoolean("contact", true)&& getDetails(sender)){
                 abortBroadcast();


            }






             else {}}


            return;
        }
    }

    // ...
}


boolean getDetails(String Phonumber){
    Boolean answer=null;

    Log.i("sss", "to here");


Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    // ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();


// Cursor cur = context.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };



Log.i("sss", "to here1");



Cursor names = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);



//int indexName = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
int indexNumber = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
Log.i("sss", "to here n"+indexNumber);


names.moveToFirst();
do {

    Log.i("sss", names.getString(indexNumber));

       String number = names.getString(indexNumber);

  number.replace(" ", "");
     if(number.startsWith("0")){
         number="+98"+context.getString(1,number.length());}

  if(Phonumber.startsWith("0")){
     Phonumber="+98"+Phonumber.substring(1,Phonumber.length());}



     if (number.equals(Phonumber))

     {answer=true;}

} while (names.moveToNext());
return answer;
}

}
```

Comment: You can clear see in the error report...error say NPE at blocker.activity.contactsearch.search(contactsearch.java:37) so I feel error is at line -->boolean str=Search.search(sender); alternatively you can click on that line in the report it will take you to the location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a member at the top of your class, but never assign a valid reference to it:

```
Context context = null;
```

As such, `context` is still `null` when you call:

```
Cursor names = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

Hence, the `NullPointerException`.

**Option 1**
Make sure you either either assign a valid reference (in `onReceive()`):

```
this.context = context;
```

**Option 2**
Or pass on the reference as a method parameter to `getDetails()`:

```
else if (preferences.getBoolean("contact", true) && getDetails(context, sender)) { ... }
```

The method itself will then look like this:

```
boolean getDetails(Context context, String Phonumber) { ... }
```

If you use the second option, you can remove the line that says `Context context = null;`, as it's no longer used. Your IDE may already hint at that (I know Android Studio definitely does, but not sure about Eclipse).